# Take list of all objects ids

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

I have **model Product** where as primary key use code field which is **UUID**. I want take list of ids of all products.

I want list like this:

`['14431ec4-3224-480f-85e2-b541891919b1', '6e54636b-7283-4504-a16f-f54d29db26f2']`

I tried next code but it return me this:

```
[UUID('14431ec4-3224-480f-85e2-b541891919b1'), UUID('6e54636b-7283-4504-a16f-f54d29db26f2')]
```

**models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.UUIDField(_('Code'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

**views.py:**

```
products = Product.objects.all()
product_ids = []
for product in products:
    product_ids.append(product.code)
print(product_ids)
```

*How to fix this problem?*

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) with `flat=True` on your [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference) object to flatten the list of model's `code` and [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to type-case each UUID object to string as:

```
map(str, Product.objects.all().values_list('code', flat=True))
```

Please also see [UUID examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#example) for the typical usage of the [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

This is just because it is a `UUID` field. If you definitely need them as strings, just call `str()`:

```
product_ids = [str(product.code) for product in products]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get string value using .hex from `uuid` as follows:

```
 ids = [product.uuid.hex for product in products]
```